# Run a JUnit test from my java application

Tags: java, exception, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to run a Junit test from inside my java application.

this is the JUnit test file

```
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner;
import com.intuit.karate.cucumber.KarateStats;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

@CucumberOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"})
public class TestParallel {
    @Test
    public void testParallel() {
        KarateStats stats = CucumberRunner.parallel(getClass(), 5, "target/surefire-reports");
        assertTrue("scenarios failed", stats.getFailCount() == 0);
    }
}
```

When I try calling it from the main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
    Result result = junit.run(TestParallel.class);
}
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intuit/karate/cucumber/CucumberRunner
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Where is com/intuit/karate/cucumber/CucumberRunner class located? Are you sure the proper library in class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your response. I managed to get it to work by deleting

```
      <scope>test</scope>
```

from the pom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the class that could not be found on your classpath. If using Maven, verify that your scope is **correctly defined**. It should not be `<scope>provided</scope>` for the scope, for instance.

Why do you call your classes from the `static main()`-context even?

If you really want to execute your tests like that, make sure that you remove the `<scope>test</scope>` for the cucumber stuff.